# How do I render this partial view passing an integer to my ActionResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

This is my  ProductAttributeValueListAll form it displays fine until I try to add the partial view I get the following error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type '<>f__AnonymousType4`1[System.Int32]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[Nop.Admin.Models.Catalog.ProductModel+ProductVariantAttributeValueModel]'.

```
 @model IEnumerable<Nop.Admin.Models.Catalog.ProductModel.ProductVariantAttributeModel>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ProductAttributeValueListAll";
}

<h2>ProductAttributeValueListAll</h2>

<p>
    @Html.ActionLink("Create New", "Create")
</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductAttributeId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.ProductAttribute)
        </th>


    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductAttributeId)
        </td>

        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.ProductAttribute)
            <br />

          @Html.Partial("ProductAssociatedList", new { productVariantAttributeId = item.ProductAttributeId });

        </td>


    </tr>
}
```

This is the Code for the action in the controller for the partial view I am trying to call

```
    [ChildActionOnly]
public ActionResult ProductAssociatedList(int productVariantAttributeId)
{
    var values = _productAttributeService.GetProductVariantAttributeValues(productVariantAttributeId);

    var ProductVariantAttributeValue = values

        .Select(x =>
        {
             var associatedProduct = _productService.GetProductById(x.AssociatedProductId);
            //var pictureThumbnailUrl = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(x.PictureId, 75, false);
            ////little hack here. Grid is rendered wrong way with <inmg> without "src" attribute
            //if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(pictureThumbnailUrl))
            //    pictureThumbnailUrl = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(null, 1, true);
             var pvaModel = new ProductModel.ProductVariantAttributeValueModel()
             {
                 Id = x.Id,
                 ProductVariantAttributeId = x.ProductVariantAttributeId,
                 AttributeValueTypeId = x.AttributeValueTypeId,
                 AttributeValueTypeName = x.AttributeValueType.GetLocalizedEnum(_localizationService, _workContext),
                 AssociatedProductId = x.AssociatedProductId,
                 AssociatedProductName = associatedProduct != null ? associatedProduct.Name : "",
                 Name = x.ProductVariantAttribute.AttributeControlType != AttributeControlType.ColorSquares ? x.Name : string.Format("{0} - {1}", x.Name, x.ColorSquaresRgb),
                 IsPreSelected = x.IsPreSelected,
                     DisplayOrder = x.DisplayOrder

             };
                   // pvaModel.ViewEditUrl = Url.Action("ProductAssociatedList", "Product", new { productVariantAttributeId = x.Id });
                // pvaModel.ViewEditText = string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("Admin.Catalog.Products.ProductVariantAttributes.Attributes.Values.ViewLink"), x.ProductVariantAttribute.ProductVariantAttributeValues != null ? x.ProductVariantAttribute.ProductVariantAttributeValues.Count : 0);
             return pvaModel;

        })
        .ToList();
    //var model =  ProductVariantAttributeValue.ToList();

    return View(ProductVariantAttributeValue);
}
```

This is the cshtml partial view I am trying to insert:

```
    @model IEnumerable<ProductModel.ProductVariantAttributeValueModel>

<p>

</p>
<table>
    <tr>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssociatedProductId)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
        </th>
        <th>
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.AssociatedProductName)
        </th>
        <th>

        </th>
        <th></th>
    </tr>

@foreach (var item in Model) {
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssociatedProductId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Name)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.AssociatedProductName)
        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
        <td>

        </td>
    </tr>
}

</table>
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong here, anyone got any answers

Answer (score 0):

You should call the action method directly, not the partial view. The way you are doing calling `Html.Partial` you are passing a `Int` as model for the `View`, not calling the action method, so:

```
@Html.Action("ProductAssociatedList", new { productVariantAttributeId = item.ProductAttributeId })
```

OR

```
@{Html.RenderAction("ProductAssociatedList", new { productVariantAttributeId = item.ProductAttributeId });}
```

Reference: [MSDN ChildActionExtensions.Action](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee703423%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)